# find the kth smallest number in java

Tags: java, data-structures

Below is the java code to find the kth smallest number in array.
This code is for elementary version, not using pivot-index.

```
class Func {
    int kthSmallest(int arr[], int smallestIndex, int size){
        int smallest = arr[0];
        int removeLocation=0;
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            if(arr[i] < smallest){
                smallest = arr[i];
                removeLocation = i;
            }
        }
        for(int i=removeLocation; i<size; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
        if(smallestIndex == 1) {
            return smallest;
        } else return kthSmallest(arr, smallestIndex-1, size-1);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Func test = new Func();
        int number = test.kthSmallest(new int[]{3,1,2,4,5}, 2, 5);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

the result is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

I cannot find where that error is coming out.

Comment: `arr[i] = arr[i+1];` the problem is here. You are trying to access the i + 1 th element when your i = size-1

Comment: `arr[i] = arr[i+1];` what happens when i is the last valid index?

Comment: why dont u just sort the array, and pick up the k-th number then?

Comment: @Tobii, sorting is performance costly. But if he doesn't care about speed then maybe sorting is the way to go

Comment: @Schidu Luca, that's why I asked :)

Comment: Thanks all for giving some help. I know that code is inefficient but just practicing how to express the code with my own

Comment: Save yourself a lot of trouble and learn to use your debugger. With a debugger, you can find this type of problem in seconds.

Comment: @Jim Mischel 

Mischel appreciate for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in second for loop you accessing the more out of range by i+1 modify as per below

```
for(int i=removeLocation; i<size-1; i++){
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
```

## OUT

```
2
```